# JavaScript: Add event within loop--clousure issue

Tags: javascript, closures

I want to add event to li within a for loop.

I know what always goes wrong: the `i` that the closure can access to is the last value of `i`. `i` needs to be locked in the closure.

To solve this, use immediately invoke function expression.

What i don't understand is why this doesn't work!

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.onclick = (function(i2){
        return slideTo(i2);    // slideTo is a global function
    }(i));
```

But i know this will work:

```
li.onclick = (function(i2){
    return function(){ 
        slideTo(i2);        // slideTo is a global function
    }
}(i));
```

Why do i need to put `slideTo(i)` into an anonymous function???

What's the difference between these two expression??

Thank you a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, you are just assigning the value of `slideTo(i2)` to the `onclick`:

```
li.onclick = (function(i2){
    // Here, "i2" is **immediately** used to invoke
    // slideTo(i2). It is invoked right here, in 
    // every loop iteration. 
    return slideTo(i2);
}(i));
```

The above will be evaluated in every loop iteration, so it's equivalent to:

```
li.onclick = slideTo(i);
```

In contract, in second example you create a proper closure thus assigning a **function** (not a **value** like in first scenario) to `li.onclick` listener:

```
li.onclick = (function(i2){
    // Here, "i2" is in a scope, but it's **not immediately** used.
    // Instead, you are returning function which will be assigned
    // to "li.onclick" but with THIS scope (i.e. scope with
    // "i2" value).
    //
    // New scope is created in every loop iteration, but the following
    // function **is not called** in a loop.
    return function() {
         // Later, when <li> is clicked, slideTo(i2) will be called.
         slideTo(i2);
    }
}(i));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! So if i got it right, the first scenario will call slideTo(is2) immediately and it returns a value. While the second one will return a function: function(){slideTo(i2)} as a whole, that not be called now. Am I right?

Comment: @flyaway - yes. In second example the whole expression `(function (i2) { return function () { slideTo(i2); }}(i))` is evaluated. The outer function is immediately invoked, so what you get is `li.onclick = function () { slideTo(i2) }` BUT with different scope (thanks to the outer function.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd form is required to create a *new* variable binding (namely, `i2`) - the first form is *evaluated immediately* (it does not return a function-object which does the later work) and thus not a "callback".

Remember that *only new function scopes* create new variables. Without the double-closure you will be referencing the *same* `i` variable. An alternative is to use `Function.bind` (which can itself be emulated with a closure).